# Yup validation if statement not working as required

Tags: javascript, react-hook-form, yup

I'm trying to only validate React Hook Form when the **is:** is true then run the **then:** validation.
What I have so far is showing isValid= true in React-hook-form which it should not until all statements have been validated.

Sequance of validation should be:
show invalid and when the **is=true** then run validation in the **then:** and update react hook form isValid based only on the then value ?

```
const regex =
  /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/

export const emailSchema = yup.object().shape({
  email: yup
    .string()
  .when({
    is: (val: string) => {
      console.log('val = ', val, ' test = ', /@.+/.test(val))
      return /@.+/.test(val)
    },
    then: yup.string().matches(regex, { message: 'Invalid Email' }),
  }),
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check documentation https://github.com/jquense/yup#schemawhenkeys-string--string-builder-object--values-any-schema--schema-schema

it says `Schema.when(keys: string | string[], builder: object | (values: any[], schema) => Schema): Schema` means first is keys and builder

in your case key is 'email'

```
const regex =
  /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/

export const emailSchema = yup.object().shape({
  email: yup
    .string()
  .when('email', { // changed here
    is: (val: string) => {
      return /@.+/.test(val)
    },
    then: yup.string().matches(regex, { message: 'Invalid Email' }),
  }),
})
```

Comment: I tried adding email before I posted this and I got this error: Uncaught Error: application 'myProject' died in status LOADING_SOURCE_CODE: Cyclic dependency, node was:"email"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64020518/error-cyclic-dependency-with-yup-validation try adding cyclic dependency inside .shape as follows `.shape({..... your rest code here},[email, email])`

Comment: @PrashantJangam
  Sorry not getting what you are suggesting ?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to test if the email is in proper format then run the `regex` pattern check. If this is the case, you can use below schema. you don't need to add `.when` schema for that. `yup` provides `.email` schema to check email format/type
https://github.com/jquense/yup#stringemailmessage-string--function-schema

```
const regex =
  /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/

export const emailSchema = yup.object().shape({
  email: yup
    .string()
    .required('Email is required')
    .email('Invalid Email')
    .matches(regex, 'Invalid Email'),
})
```